# How to apply multiple CSS background properties using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, css, background, gradient

I need to dynamically generate CSS patterns, for which I need to apply several `linear-gradient` or `radial-gradient` to the CSS `background` property on the client side. And I need to dynamically change the parameters of these gradients at the same time.

If I use this, only one gradient is applied to the background:

```
var color1;
var color2;
var color3;
var color4;
var direction1;
var direction2;
var direction3;
var direction4;
var size;

$("body").css({
    background: 'linear-gradient('+direction1+', '+color1+' 25%, transparent 25%) '+size+'/2 0,
                 linear-gradient('+direction2+', '+color2+' 25%, transparent 25%) '+size+'/2 0,
                 linear-gradient('+direction3+', '+color3+' 25%, transparent 25%),
                 linear-gradient('+direction4+', '+color4+' 25%, transparent 25%)'
});
```

Same thing happens here, since each property overwrites the other:

```
$("body").css('background','linear-gradient('+direction1+', '+color1+' 25%, transparent 25%) '+size+'/2 0)');
$("body").css('background','linear-gradient('+direction2+', '+color2+' 25%, transparent 25%) '+size+'/2 0)');
$("body").css('background','linear-gradient('+direction3+', '+color3+' 25%, transparent 25%)');
$("body").css('background','linear-gradient('+direction4+', '+color4+' 25%, transparent 25%)');
```

I've tried using `LessCSS`, but it's too CPU intense, since it needs to render a new stylesheet each time the css property changes, which is each time the mouse moves (that's a requirement).

Note that I need to apply ALL of the gradients at once, not let the browser decide which one to use.

**Question 1:**
Any idea how I could do this more efficiently?

**Question 2:**
I've also noticed that when I declare multiple properties in one declaration (ie. also `width` and `height` next to the `linear-gradient` in a `background` property or just even just `width` and `height` using the `background-size` property) only the first one gets applied. How to get around this?

Comment: i don't think you will get a result, with the way you try, an additional way, you could try is to have 4 `<div/>` tag for each direction with the same size as `body` of html page, think something like `layers`, or maybe you could work something with images

Comment: thanks for the reply, that might work (I'll try it) for question 1, but it still fails for question 2, any ideas for that?

Comment: So I've tried layering divs and it works perfectly, they just need to be stacked up in reverse order to get the same effect. Thanks!

Comment: Also for Qustion 2, it now seems to work properly, I'm not sure what I did differently.

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like this:

```
$("body").css({
    'backgroundImage': 'linear-gradient('+direction1+', '+color1+', transparent), 
        linear-gradient('+direction2+', '+color2+', transparent), 
        linear-gradient('+direction3+', '+color3+', transparent),  
        linear-gradient('+direction4+', '+color4+', transparent)'
    })
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but its the same, doesnt matter if I use background-image or background or any of their other syntax variations. I've fixed the variables here though (they were correct in my code), thanks for that. Please check the updated questions, if you have any more ideas